# Using C# Regular expressions how do i match the vertical bar as a literal?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a program in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio, i need the program to match the vertical bar, but when I try to escape it like this `"\|"` it gives me an unrecognized escape sequence error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In C#

```
string test = "\|";
```

Is going to fail because this is a C# string escape sequence, and no such escape exists.  Because you are trying to include a backslash in the string, you need to escape the slash so the string actually contains a slash:

```
string test = "\\|";
```

What will actually be stored in this string is `\|`

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get an unrecognized escape sequence is that backslash is used as an escape character in C# string literals as well as in regex.

You have several choices to fix this:

- Use verbatim literals, i.e. `@"\|"`, or
- Use a second escape inside a regular literal, i.e. `"\\|"`, or
- Use a character class, i.e. `[|]`

The third one is my personal favorite, because it does not require counting backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

The string is treating "\|" as an escaped pipe in C#. Try "\|" to escape the \ so that the regex actually sees the \| you want.

Comment: No i want to escape the pipe it wont let me.